# iterator compound assignment operator

Tags: c++, iterator

In C++ primer 4th edition by Lippman, compound assignment operators for iterator for vector and deque are given :

```
iter1 += iter2 
iter1 -= iter2
```

Compound-assignment versions of iterator addition and subtraction. Assigns the value of adding or subtracting iter1 and iter2 into iter1.

But when I want to use them, it gives error. Moreover what does it mean to provide compound assignment operators for iterators anyway?

Comment: Are you sure `iter2` is an iterator, not a number?

Comment: Quite, KennyTM. I can understand adding a number to an iterator, to point a few places further on, but adding an iterator to another iterator seems meaningless. You wouldn't add two pointers together and expect to get anything worthwhile, after all.

Comment: @KennyTM..The book says so. I also think that iter2 should be a number.

Answer (score 4):

I looked this up in Lippman. To me, it looks like an error. Random access iterators (the kind of iterator provided by vector and deque) offer compound assignment of the form

```
iter += n
iter -= n
```

See e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/

Compound assignment of the form Lippman wrote doesn't make sense when you look at the resulting types.